# Assign 0 or 1 based on conditional probability + previous simulated data

Tags: r, dataframe, simulator

I'm doing a simulation study and I have some problem generating data that meet certain conditions.

My first simulated data looks like below.

```
       A1    A2
  1    0.8    6  
  2    0.5    3   
  3    0.9    2 
  ...
  1000
```

This is how I generated A1 & A2

```
set.seed(47)
df <- data.frame(A1 = rnorm(1000, mean=0.7, sd=0.1), A2 = rnorm(1000, mean=4, sd=1))
df
```

In tabular format, this is how the conditional statement looks where 0=fail and 1=pass and the output in the table is the probability of getting a 1 for A3.

```
   A1  0     1
A2
     
0      0.1   0.3
1      0.9   0.7
```

Here is the explanation in words:

I want to generate a third row (A3) based on conditional probabilities of the first two rows. This is the condition I want to apply.

1. If A1>=0.7 (pass) & A2>=0.8 (pass) --> A3=1 with a 70% probability (implying %30 of zero)
2. If A1>=0.7 (pass) & A2<0.8  (fail)  --> A3=1 with a 30% probability
3. If A1<0.7  (fail) & A2>=0.8 (pass) --> A3=1 with a 90% probability
4. If A1<0.7  (fail) & A2<0.8  (fail)--> A3=1 with a 10% probability

I hope my logic makes sense. Please let me know if I need more data or words to better explain. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a little trick here of converting logical vectors to integers then counting in binary.

If you do the logical test `df$A1 >= 0.7` you get a vector of TRUE and FALSE values. If instead you do `as.numeric(df$A1 >= 0.7)` you get the equivalent vector of 1s and 0s. The trick is to do this for both variables, but multiply the second vector by 2. Now if you add both vectors together, you will get a number between 0 and 3 that corresponds to your truth table:

- A1 pass, A2 pass = 3
- A1 fail, A2 pass = 2
- A1 pass, A2 fail = 1
- A1 fail, A2 fail = 0.

Note that if we add one to these numbers, we get a value between one and four. We can therefore use them as indexes of our probability vector:

```r
probs <- c(0.1, 0.3, 0.9, 0.7)[(df$A1 >= 0.7) + 2*(df$A2 >= 0.8)]
```

That means we can generate the random binary numbers using `rbinom` like so:

```r
df$A3 <- rbinom(1000, 1, probs)
```

Resulting in:

```r
head(df)
#>          A1       A2 A3
#> 1 0.8994696 5.345481  1
#> 2 0.7711143 3.662635  1
#> 3 0.7185405 3.125840  1
#> 4 0.6718235 3.914527  0
#> 5 0.7108776 3.366858  1
#> 6 0.5914263 2.082173  0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Is there a way to make A3 as a value between 1-5 based on the probs?